# Xamarin Forms: Using of a configuration file

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mobile, configuration, xamarin-studio

Currently I am working on my xamarin application which has different settings, to make it easy for my self in the future, I created a configuration file (appsettings.json) to import default settings of my application so that I wouldn't need to code it from the begining.

**My question is this:** How would I use my config file?

*By how I mean, let's say that I would like to use that configuration file in order to import my applications default settings, must I have, for instance, a "Get all settings" button in my application in order to get all default settings of my application?*

You see, this is the first time that I'm working with configuration files so I am having trouble to understand its principles.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Your question is very broad.  What kind of settings do you mean?  For example, you could specify the base url for your webservices in a config file and read that in at app startup and set the value instead of just having it hardcoded.

Comment: By settings I mean, for instance, color of the mainpage, SettingsPageTitleSize or LoginWrongPassWordColor. That is excatly what I want to do but what do you mean by "app startup"? Do you mean App.xaml.cs?

Comment: yes.  When your **app starts** read the config settings.  In `OnStart`

Comment: Alright I get it now.. But if I want to read it in **OnStart**, how would the code look? I have, as I mentioned a appsettings.json file and a AppSettings.Manager.cs class to, for example, store my appsettings in memory for quick and easy access. @Jason

Comment: Read the json file using System.IO.  Deserialize it using Newtonsoft.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem @Jason!